# .exe not opening C# window form application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project, windows

i have made my setup and deployment project of C# windows form Application by following these steps exactly http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/CustomDocument3235. it successfully make installation project for me which i then install on another PC successfully, but when i open that .exe file it through a error **"Application has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience"**.
any idea, solution or suggestion to solve this issue.
thanks in advance.

Comment: When you deployed the application, did you make sure to include all of its dependencies in the installer/project?

Comment: ya i exactly followed these steps  http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/CustomDocument3235

Comment: Does that other computer have the right version of .net framework installed, or any other library that needs to be there?

Comment: ya all the prerequisites are installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the extra dependencies from my installer and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Check the application/system event logs, they might contain more details.

You can run the event viewer using this command :

*eventvwr*

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an answer.

Comment: My bad, I'll know for next time.

Comment: sorry i didn't got u?